# EntityFramework not updating enum value in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Important note**: the column *online* in my MySQL table is of type **enum** and I'm not allowed to change the database

So here's my entity:

```
public enum onlineStatus { online = 1, offline = 0 };
public onlineStatus online { get; set; }
```

And in my db context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public void AddUser(User user) // I'm using a custom membership provider that calls this method
    {
        try
        {
            user.online = 0; // this will give me the word "offline"

            Users.Add(user);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow user.online = 0; doesn't add to the database. And how do I make it so that it saves the value 0 instead of offline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which EF version you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818622/how-to-map-an-enum-property-in-entity-framework-4

Comment: Using EF 6 I do believe

Comment: From version 5, EF added inherent support for Enum as data type. Did you check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: Oh and the column "online" in my table is of type enum (MySQL enum)

Comment: I am not sure why you have column type enum, i created a console app with EF6 and used your code all works fine... I see column in DB as int...

Comment: It does not store offline in DB, it store 0 or 1. I can see that in my DB. And the data type in DB is int. I can add the code I wrote if that helps. Something to do with the way you have setup your DB.

Comment: If I change the data type in db to int it works. But I'm not supposed to do any changes to the db. Any solution?

Comment: Oh i see... It becomes interesting question then... My suggestion is to highlight this point in your OP. May be someone knows a solution.

Comment: Solution: user.online = Snowy2.Entities.User.onlineStatus.online; will save the value 1 in the database. Can't believe this took me almost a day, lol.

Comment: Ah I had done the same in my demo. user.Online = User.OnlineStatus.Online; But thought your column data type is ENUM.